# Draw Marker of Store along the route between two point

Tags: java, android, google-maps

> I have to show stores on Google map  between two Locations.

Suppose I have `5000 stores` all over the country. But how could I only draw store marker between my routes. I mean show stores coming in my way on Map. As Latitude longitude don't change gradually while moving b/w two points. How could I query like

**Read all store which lie on the given route between two points.**

As route `consist of polyLines` I think I should create circular area between each polyline and If any `store lat lng lie` in that area **draw it on Map**. But when I have a big polyline it's circle will be bigger and I don't want to show store that are far away from my routes.

I need a better approach to show my store on map in my route. And I need it before moving.

Comment: What if you calculate distance from your location to every store location? and show store if that belong to 200 ft or what ever distance min as per your requirement

Comment: It will work only if I start moving and at each changedLocation I  hit and compare Lat Lng  . But I need to draw those store initially.  Not at run time(while walking)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a circular region or a polygon. Consider the documentation of Polyline. I found a very helpful method here

```
isLocationOnPath(LatLng point, java.util.List<LatLng> polyline, boolean geodesic, double tolerance)
```

Computes whether the given point lies on or near a polyline, within a specified tolerance in meters.

For further detail consider this
http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html